# Repeating the Header of a DataList

Tags: c#, header, datalist

I'm using an `asp:DataList`.  I have the `HeaderTemplate` and the `ItemTemplate`, and those both work fine.  However, I'd like to be able to repeat the Header above each Item, rather than just once at the top.

1. Is this possible?  Would I be better off using a different control?
2. Can I make this configurable (ie, can it be turned on & off in the code behind)?

(Using C# 2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28VS.80%29.aspx) control.

Comment: I really didn't want to have to go down to the Repeater, but it looks like I do.  Thanks.